# Installing plpythonu on Windows

Tags: postgresql, plpython

I'm trying to install plpython on a postgres server on a Windows machine. When I issue the command `CREATE EXTENSION plpython3u;` in postgres, I get the following error, which I'm trying to find the source of.

```
ERROR: could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib/plpython3.dll": The specified module could not be found.
```

This file exists, which I presume means that Windows can't find one of the files it depends on. When I open the plpython3.dll with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), it tells me it can't locate the GPSVC.dll.

Is it likely that this missing dll would cause the `CREATE EXTENSION` command to fail? I found a .dll with the same name in C:\Windows\System32 and copied it over to C:\Windows\SysWOW64, but this did not resolve the probelm, and although dependency walker now finds the .dll, it raises several other errors about having modules with different CPU types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use specific python version on Windows. I could get it running with python 3.2.x with postgres 9.3

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question, but thought I would post to save someone the headaches I went through trying to fix this...

I had the same error trying to add pl python using Postgres 9.5. Dependency walker showed that plpython3.dll was looking for python33.dll, so I installed python 3.3 and added the install directory into my path and that seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks your answer saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Further, need to restart the Postgres service for any changes in system environment variables to take affect.

Comment: A custom Python install under the user directory did not work for me, I had to use the version from the Stackbuilder Postgres app.