# could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.4/lib/plpython3.dll": The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am working on windows 10 with PG 9.4.1 and Python 3.6

When I run the following query, `CREATE LANGUAGE plpython3u;` I am getting the error mentioned in the title which is `could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.4/lib/plpython3.dll": The specified module could not be found.`

I used dependency walker and like in this post [Installing plpythonu on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001890/installing-plpythonu-on-windows), it was looking for python33.dll actually.Have tried to rename the file to python33.dll but that doesn't seem to work.
I have also done `pip install pg`

I am not sure about installing python 3.4 because my guess is that if anything works with Python 3.4, should also work with 3.6

I tried it in other people machines also and got the same response there too. Tried reinstalling PG also, but nothing seems to work.

My main work here is to run a PG function which would be calling an AWS Lambda function. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I have "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\lib\" added to PATH system variable also.

Comment: You didn't rename `plpython3.dll`, right? Since you are installing a binary package, you need the matching version of Python installed, I guess.

Comment: Didn't rename the file, made a copy of plpython3.dll and named it plpython33.dll. Can you guide me please how to check matching pyhton version.? I went through the release notes of PG 9.4.1 but couldn't find anything related https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/release-9-4-1.html

Comment: That's not in the PostgreSQL documentation; you'd have to ask the provider of the binaries you are using. Perhaps Python 3.3?

Comment: Shouldn't python 3.6 also work if 3.3 is required.?

Comment: I'm just guessing. But if it looks for `python33.dll`, you will have to install something that provides that file.